# length of curve under surjective map

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

Suppose $h$ is a continuous surjective map
$h: R^{n} \rightarrow R^q$.
Let $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow R^n$  be a curve from $\gamma(0) = x_1$ to $\gamma(1) = x_2$, where $x_1 \in R^n$ and $x_2 \in R^n$.

Under the map $h$, can we say there exists another curve $\chi: [0,1] \rightarrow R^q$ from $\chi(0) = h(x_1)$ to $\chi(1) = h(x_2)$?

It seems to me that the following inequality should hold true. However, I don't how know to prove (or disprove!) it:

$$\int^1_0 \sqrt{\chi'(s)^T\chi'(s)}ds \leq  \int^1_0 \sqrt{\gamma'(s)^T\frac{\partial h(\gamma(s))}{\partial{x}}^T \frac{\partial h(\gamma(s))}{\partial{x}}\gamma'(s)}ds$$